# Chromatic number of $(n, [n]^k)$

Tags: graph-colorings, hypergraph

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a non-negative integer, we consider it as a cardinal, so $n = \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$. If $X$ is a set, and $\kappa$ is a cardinal, we let $[X]^\kappa$ be the collection of subsets of $X$ having cardinality $\kappa$.

If $H=(V,E)$ is a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) and $\kappa\neq \emptyset$ is a cardinal, a map $c:V\to \kappa$ is said to be a *coloring* if the restriction $c\restriction_e$ is non-constant whenever $e\in E$ has more than $1$ element. The smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there is a coloring map $c:V\to \kappa$ is said to be the *chromatic number* of $H=(V,E)$, and we denote it by $\chi(H)$.

**Question.** Given integers $n\geq k \geq 3$, what is the value of $\chi(n,[n]^k)$ in terms of $n$ and $k$?

Comment: I don't think this is the chromatic number and maybe should be called something else in order to avoid confusion. Usually, I think, one requires $c$ restricted to $e$ to be injective rather than non-constant.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam what you say reduces to a graph coloring (for a graph which is the union of cliques on the edges), so usually a hypergraph coloring is defined as in OP.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Thanks for correcting me. I guess what I mentioned is the chromatic number of the associated "collinearity graph" as in the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869315005657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $\lceil \frac{n}{k-1}\rceil$, simply since every color class must contain at most $k-1$ elements.